# Using pip to install a package for a previous version of python

Tags: python

I have python3.10 on my desktop but I need 3.7 for work.

I follow the [instructions here](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-python-ubuntu/) to install python3.7 alongside my 3.10 and they work great.

However, when I run python3.7 on the checked out code I find I need to use pip to install a missing package.  However, I only have one pip3 executable which sensibly installs all modules into the 3.10 directory.

How do I get pip to install packages for the 3.7 version of python?

Comment: you will go to the folder of the python 3.7 after that you go into the folder scripts and click on the link of the path above and write cmd and write your pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```bash
python3.7 -m pip install mymodule
```